# How to use jq to merge a list of dictionaries into one dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, jq, jsonparser

I'm developing jq expressions on the command line.  (I plan to use the expression  with `pyjq` in python to parse http requests.)

The following command line:

```
$ cat some.json | jq '.collection.rows[].rowAnswers | map({ (.refCode) : .answers[0].responseText }) '
```

Results in two items.

```
[
  {
    "NAME": "some_name1"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "code1"
  },
  {
    "SERVER"": "server1"
  }
]
[
  {
    "NAME": "name2"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "code2"
  },
  {
    "SERVER"": "server2"
  }
]
```

This is a nice intermediate step.  I'd like to merge each list of dictionaries into one dictionary.  I'd like the final result to be:

```
{
    "NAME": "some_name1"
    "CODE": "code1"
    "SERVER"": "server1"
}
{
    "NAME": "name2"
    "CODE": "code2"
    "SERVER"": "server2"
}
```

If that's too difficult, then `[merge_dict][merge_dict]` is good too.

There won't be any key collisions.  Also, this is simplified output.  I'd like an expression that merges all kv-pairs into one dictionary.  I don't want to hardcode the actual name of the keys in the expression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, it would seem that could achieve what you describe as your "final result" just by adding `add` to your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Do you think you can answer the same/simiilar question using jmespath?  I'll post the question soon.